# Como pasar propiedades entre dos 'child components' a traves de Router Route en React.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, router

Aun estoy aprendiendo React.js y me he encontrado con este problema.
Necesito pasar propiedades desde el 'parent' a dos 'children', ya que es este el modo en que los 'siblings' se pueden comunicar entre ellos.
He intentado usar el **render** para pasar las propiedades, pero parece no funcionar, ya que una vez llamo la función en uno de los 'children', esta no puede encontrar **cart** o **cartCopy** y resulta undefined.

Aquí se muestra el **parent component** el cual tiene **cart, setCart, cartCopy** y **setCartCopy**, los cuales necesito pasar a los 'children'.

```
function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const [cartCopy, setCartCopy] = useState([])

  return (
    <div >
      <header className="App">
        <img className='logo' src={logo} alt='NB' />
        <Router>
          <Nav />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/products" component={Products} render={(props) => <Products {...props} cart={cart} setCart={setCart} cartCopy={cartCopy} setCartCopy={setCartCopy} />} />
          <Route exact path="/cart" component={Cart} render={(props) => <Cart {...props} cart={cart} setCart={setCart} cartCopy={cartCopy} setCartCopy={setCartCopy} />} />
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Router>
      </header>
</div>

  );
}
```

Aquí, uno de los **child componentes**, que necesita recibir del **parent componente**, para poder utilizar la información.

```
const Cart = ({ cart, setCart, cartCopy, setCartCopy }) => {

    const clearCartItem = (itemID) => {

        let cartCopy = [...cart]
        cartCopy = cartCopy.filter(item => item._id != itemID);

        setCart(cartCopy);
        let cartString = JSON.stringify(cartCopy)
        localStorage.setItem('cart', cartString)
        setCartCopy(cartCopy)
    }
```

Gracias,

---

I am still learning React and I was stuck with this issue.
I need to pass props from parent to two children as this is the way the siblings can communicate with eachother.

I tried to use **render** to pass the props, but it does not work.

Here the **parent component** which has **cart, setCart, cartCopy and setCartCopy**, which is what I need to pass to the children.

```
function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const [cartCopy, setCartCopy] = useState([])

  return (
    <div >
      <header className="App">
        <img className='logo' src={logo} alt='NB' />
        <Router>
          <Nav />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/products" component={Products} render={(props) => <Products {...props} cart={cart} setCart={setCart} cartCopy={cartCopy} setCartCopy={setCartCopy} />} />
          <Route exact path="/cart" component={Cart} render={(props) => <Cart {...props} cart={cart} setCart={setCart} cartCopy={cartCopy} setCartCopy={setCartCopy} />} />
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Router>
      </header>
</div>

  );
}
```

Here one **child component**, which needs to recieve from parent in order to use the data:

```
const Cart = ({ cart, setCart, cartCopy, setCartCopy }) => {

    const clearCartItem = (itemID) => {

        let cartCopy = [...cart]
        cartCopy = cartCopy.filter(item => item._id != itemID);

        setCart(cartCopy);
        let cartString = JSON.stringify(cartCopy)
        localStorage.setItem('cart', cartString)
        setCartCopy(cartCopy)
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO in Spanish, please translate your question or it will be closed

Comment: Realice una modificación al primer ejemplo para poder emular el error que obtienes de tu lado, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que el origen del problema, este en la forma de configurar el componente `Route`, se están usando dos propiedades `component` y `render` al mismo tiempo.

Consideremos el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
//const Router = window.ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
const Route =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Link;

function App(){
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([]);
  const [cartCopy, setCartCopy] = React.useState([]);
  
  return(
    <div>
    <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
      <Link to="/cart">Ve a Cart</Link>
      <Route path="/cart" 
        component={Cart} //se pasa primero cart sin props custom
        render={(props) => 
            <Cart {...props} 
              cart={cart} 
              setCart={setCart}
              cartCopy={cartCopy}
              setCartCopy={setCartCopy} />} />
    </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const Cart = ({ cart, setCart, cartCopy, setCartCopy }) => {
  console.log("cart", cart);
  console.log("cartCopy", cartCopy);
  console.log("setCart", setCart);
  console.log("setCartCopy", setCartCopy);
return <h3>In cart</h3>
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router@5.0.0/umd/react-router.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
    


 

<div id="root"></div>
```

Al ejecutar el ejemplo, dando click a `Ve a cart`, los `console.log` del componente `Cart` mostrarán `undefined`.

Se observa que `Route` da prioridad a la propiedad `component` sobre  la propiedad `render`, por lo que pasa `Cart` sin `props` personalizadas:

```
component={Cart} //aqui se pasa primero cart sin props custom
```

Por lo tanto el componente `Cart` no tiene capturas de ninguna `prop` personalizada como:

```
cart, setCart, cartCopy, setCartCopy
```

Entonces, para este caso usar las propiedades `component` y `render` al mismo tiempo no parece ser un patrón válido, pues `Router` da prioridad a `component` sobre `render`.

#### Solución

Cuando se necesitan pasar `props` personalizadas a un componente por medio de `Route`, el patrón que parece funcionar es usando la propiedad `render`:

```js
//const Router = window.ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
const Route =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Link;

function App(){
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([]);
  const [cartCopy, setCartCopy] = React.useState([]);
  
  return(
    <div>
    <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
      <Link to="/cart">Ve a Cart</Link>
      <Route path="/cart" 
        render={(props) => 
            <Cart {...props} 
              cart={cart} 
              setCart={setCart}
              cartCopy={cartCopy}
              setCartCopy={setCartCopy} />} />
    </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const Cart = ({ cart, setCart, cartCopy, setCartCopy }) => {
  console.log("cart", cart);
  console.log("cartCopy", cartCopy);
  console.log("setCart", setCart);
  console.log("setCartCopy", setCartCopy);
return <h3>In cart</h3>
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router@5.0.0/umd/react-router.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
    


 

<div id="root"></div>
```

En el ejemplo anterior yá se configuró el componente `Route` solo con la propiedad `render`, ahí es donde se especifica que el componente `Cart` va a recibir `props` personalizadas; al entrar a la ruta `/cart`, ya se observan todas las `props` capturadas en el scope, dentro de los `console.log`.

#### Notas de campo

Esta validación puede ser problemática:

```
cartCopy.filter(item => item._id != itemID);
```

Yo usaría el operador `!==` (not equal value or not equal type):

```
cartCopy.filter(item => item._id !== itemID);
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.